# How should I use swift dictionary array to get all value?

Tags: arrays, swift

My dictionary is like this:

```
["Coke": ["1", "80"], "Appetizer": ["3", "70"], "Water": ["4", "70"],

"Noodle": ["2", "40"], "Pizza": ["7", "80"],  "Steak": ["7", "60"]]
```

The value is an array , it includes two values

first number is like how many item you order

second number is like subtotal

I'm just wondering how should I get the second number and save into the new variable ?

because I need to add all number to represent total price

Comment: You are encouraged to use a custom struct instead of the array, It makes life easier.

Comment: Go for `Structs` as it acts as a _Model_ which can make your code much cleaner and _avoid typos_ !

Comment: I agree with @vadian.
However if you have no choice but to stick with dictionary/array format, you can add up the subtotal by
let total = dict.values.compactMap ({ Int($0.last ?? "") }).reduce(0, +)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let dict = ["Coke": ["1", "80"], "Appetizer": ["3", "70"], "Water": ["4", "70"], "Noodle": ["2", "40"], "Pizza": ["7", "80"],  "Steak": ["7", "60"]]
```

### Short Answer (directly for your question)

```
var price = dict.values.reduce(0, { $0 + Double($1[0])! * Double($1[1])! }) // If you need only the price, remove the multiplier
print(price) //1630.0
```

### Long Answer

Like it is always suggested on SO, you should create a data model to hold your information. In this case, it would look something like this,

```
struct Bill {
    var item: String
    var amount: Int
    var price: Double
}

// For the sake of the example i'll convert your dictionary into Price
var billArray: [Bill] = []
for (key, value) in dict {
    billArray.append(Bill(item: key, amount: Int(value[0]) ?? 0, price: Double(value[1]) ?? 0))
}

// The actual solution that you apply to the price array
var totalBill = billArray.reduce(0, { $0 + Double($1.amount) * $1.price}) // If you need only the price, remove the multipler amount
print(totalBill) //1630.0
```

Comment: Just a note: i would recommend to use another name for the struct since it can be confusing later to have a custom object 'Price' which has a property 'price'.

Comment: I really appreciate for your both answer, it works !

Answer (score 1):

Let's name our dictionary products:

```
let products = ["Coke": ["1", "80"], "Appetizer": ["3", "70"], "Water": ["4", "70"],
    "Noodle": ["2", "40"], "Pizza": ["7", "80"],  "Steak": ["7", "60"]]
```

you can extract the values by using the values methods.

```
let productValues = products.values
```

At this point `productValues` type is `[[String]]`

the get an array of the second item you can use `.map()`

```
let secondItems = productsValues.map { $0[1] }
```

---

The last part is a bit tricky because you use string but you can use `flatMap` and `reduce` to sum up the values

```
let result = secondItems.flatMap { Int($0) }.reduce(0, +)
```

Answer (score 0):

You access a dictionary like this:

```
dict["Coke"]
```

this will return:

```
["1", "80"]
```

if you want to get the second element of the list you simply do the following:

```
dict["Coke"][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work

```
let dict:[String:[String]] =  ["Coke": ["1", "80"], "Appetizer": ["3", "70"], "Water": ["4", "70"], "Noodle": ["2", "40"], "Pizza": ["7", "80"],  "Steak": ["7", "60"]]

if let val:String = dict["Coke"]?[1] {
    print(val)
}
```